# Cakephp 3.0 unit testing error

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to run some unit tests in CakePHP 3.0 but keep getting the following errors, which seem to be more Cake problems than one I constructed myself? Anyone have a similar issue? Test code is following samle in this article: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html

```
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase;

/**
 * App\Controller\UsersController Test Case
 */
class UsersControllerTest extends IntegrationTestCase
{

    /**
     * Test add method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testAdd()
    {
        $data = [
            'username' => 'testusername',
            'password' => 'testpassword',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.ie',
            'location_id' => 5,
            'gender' => 'Male',
            'info' => 'test info'
        ];
        $this->post('/users', $data);

        $this->assertResponseSuccess();
        $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
        $query = $users->find()->where(['username' => $data['username']]);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $query->count());
    }
```

Response:

```
1) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\UsersControllerTest::testIndex
Use of undefined constant TMP - assumed 'TMP'

C:\wamp\www\mysite\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Network\Session.php:141
C:\wamp\www\mysite\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Network\Session.php:95
C:\wamp\www\mysite\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCas
e.php:340
C:\wamp\www\mysite\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCas
e.php:267
C:\wamp\www\mysite\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCas
e.php:188
```

Comment: Add your test code at least (your tested code may help understand what constant `TMP` is not initialized)

Comment: Test code added now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the constants that are required for CakePHP to work. This is done for you in the tests/bootstrap.php file in the application skeleton:

https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/tests/bootstrap.php#L8

By including the application bootstrap, it also creates defines the constants here:

https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/config/paths.php#L61

Answer (score 2):

If it can help, I had the same error because the phpunit.xml.dist configuration file was missing in my project.

You can find it here: https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/phpunit.xml.dist.

Comment: your link my expire with time please consider answering question .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is What worked for me

- installed PHPUnit globally
- using composer create cakephp project using composer
- write your tests then using terminal / CMD  goto
  root of your project 
  `ex : c:/xampp/htdocs/someproject/`
- then type command

  c:/xampp/htdocs/someproject>phpunit

it will run all the tests. Hope this Works For You